# Exclude node_modules from TSLint in Ionic 2 app

Tags: typescript, ionic2, tslint

I am working on an Ionic 2 project and I ran in to some trouble with the `linter`, that I hope someone can help with or even clarify.

I am using [ng2-image-cropper](https://github.com/cstefanache/angular2-img-cropper) in the project, which seems to not have been run through a linter:

The problem is that any time I run `ionic_app_scripts serve` the terminal is spammed with linting errors even through it is clearly specified that it should exclude all `node_modules` when linting.

`tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
...
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
```

Is there any way to either disable TSLint when running `ionic_app_scripts serve` 
or let tslint know that I don't care about the code in `node_modules`?

There is already an issue on [github](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/73) but it doesn't seem to be resolved yet, so it might not be possible, but any hack would be nice

Comment: I think that particular setting goes in tsconfig.json not tslint.json..

Comment: @suraj my bad, it is in tsconfig.json

Comment: My Ionic lint task returns no linter errors, no matter how many I seed. I had to setup my own lint task. It looks similar to @iRaS's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like suraj said put this configuration to tslint.json.

I don't know what ionic2 is but you can also exclude files from the command line:

```
tslint -c tslint.json --exclude="**/*.d.ts" --exclude="node_modules/**/*.ts" "**/*.ts"
```